# from_formula() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'formula' and 'data'

Tags: python, machine-learning, python-3.7, statsmodels, linearmodels

I am getting positional arguments error for the `ols` function under `statsmodels.formula.api`

have tried for `statsmodels.regression.linear_model` and changing `OLS` to `ols` and vice-versa.

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm

X = np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(int),values=X,axis=1)

X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

regressor_OLS = sm.ols(endog = Y, exog = X_opt).fit()
```

Expected output is the fitting for the regression model. But I am getting an this error:

> from_formula() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'formula' and
>   'data'

Comment: what happens with: `regressor_OLS = sm.ols(X_opt, Y).fit()`

Comment: TypeError: from_formula() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'formula' and 'data'

Comment: I am trying to execute backward elimination::

Comment: Y - represents the set of targets. While, X_opt represents the Data. So basically, I am not understanding how the positional arguments are incorrect. Is it version problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get this example to work (I am assuming you are running the udemy machine learning course, which is line for line this example) I had to change the import statement.  The library they are using is not where the OLS function resides any longer.

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm
```

then

```
regressor_ols = lm.OLS(endog = y, exog = x_optimal).fit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
import statsmodels.api as smf;

X = np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1),dtype=np.int), values = X,axis = 1)

X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

regressor_ols = smf.OLS(y,X_opt).fit()
```

Comment: This does not work.  Running that solution you get "AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.formula' has no attribute 'OLS'

Answer (score 0):

**Remove**

`import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as sm`

**And just import *statsmodels.api* as following**

`import statsmodels.api as sm`

The course is quite old and that's why fragments of code is obsolete, no idea why they are not updating it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this module is part of  Linear_model class so use following code to make it work.

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm
X = np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(int),values=X,axis=1)

X_opt = X[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5]]

regressor_OLS = lm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt).fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm` or `import statsmodels.api as sm`

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm

X=np.append(arr=np.ones((50,1)).astype(int), values=X, axis=1)
X_opt=X[:,[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
regressor_x=sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=X_opt).fit()
regressor_x.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

X=np.insert(X,0,np.ones(X.shape[0]),axis=1)

colList=list()

for i in range(X.shape[1]):
    colList.append(i)

X_opt=np.array(X[:, colList], dtype=float)

regressor_OLS=sm.OLS(endog=y,exog=X_opt).fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
x = np.append(arr= np.ones((50, 1)).astype(int), values= x, axis=1)
x_opt = x[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=y, exog=x_opt).fit()
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm
x = np.append(arr= np.ones((50, 1)).astype(int), values= x, axis=1)
x_opt = x[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_ols = lm.OLS(endog=y, exog=x_opt).fit()
```

Comment: You need to provide some minimal explanation for the solutions you provide.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem, as auticus said, the library with the OLS function is no longer in statsmodels.formula.api. But you also must create X_otp as a list

```
import statsmodels.regression.linear_model as lm
X = np.append(arr = np.ones((50,1)).astype(int), values = X, axis = 1)
X_opt = X[:, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]].tolist()
SL = 0.05
regression_OLS = lm.OLS(endog = y, exog = X_opt). fit()
```